# Parameterising a block of similar code

Tags: r

I have dealt with parameterising code in LaTeX, so I am sure there is an equivalent for R. The following block of code is what I require to be condensed so that in future, I can optimise the code even further.

```
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "Arsenal"]       <- AP$AttackHome[1] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "Bournemouth"]   <- AP$AttackHome[2] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "Burnley"]       <- AP$AttackHome[3] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "Chelsea"]       <- AP$AttackHome[4] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "Crystal Palace"]    <- AP$AttackHome[5] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "Everton"]           <- AP$AttackHome[6] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "Hull"]          <- AP$AttackHome[7] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "Leicester"]         <- AP$AttackHome[8] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "Liverpool"]         <- AP$AttackHome[9] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "Man City"]      <- AP$AttackHome[10] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "Man United"]        <- AP$AttackHome[11] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "Middlesbrough"]     <- AP$AttackHome[12] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "Southampton"]   <- AP$AttackHome[13] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "Stoke"]             <- AP$AttackHome[14] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "Sunderland"]        <- AP$AttackHome[15] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "Swansea"]       <- AP$AttackHome[16] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "Tottenham"]         <- AP$AttackHome[17] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "Watford"]       <- AP$AttackHome[18] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "West Brom"]         <- AP$AttackHome[19] 
Model$AttackHome[Model$Home == "West Ham"]      <- AP$AttackHome[20] 

Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "Arsenal"]       <- AP$AttackAway[1]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "Bournemouth"]   <- AP$AttackAway[2]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "Burnley"]       <- AP$AttackAway[3]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "Chelsea"]           <- AP$AttackAway[4]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "Crystal Palace"]    <- AP$AttackAway[5]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "Everton"]       <- AP$AttackAway[6]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "Hull"]          <- AP$AttackAway[7]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "Leicester"]         <- AP$AttackAway[8]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "Liverpool"]         <- AP$AttackAway[9]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "Man City"]      <- AP$AttackAway[10]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "Man United"]        <- AP$AttackAway[11]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "Middlesbrough"]     <- AP$AttackAway[12]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "Southampton"]   <- AP$AttackAway[13]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "Stoke"]             <- AP$AttackAway[14]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "Sunderland"]        <- AP$AttackAway[15]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "Swansea"]           <- AP$AttackAway[16]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "Tottenham"]         <- AP$AttackAway[17]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "Watford"]       <- AP$AttackAway[18]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "West Brom"]         <- AP$AttackAway[19]
Model$AttackAway[Model$Away == "West Ham" ]         <- AP$AttackAway[20] 

Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "Arsenal"]      <- DP$DefenceHome[1] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "Bournemouth"]  <- DP$DefenceHome[2] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "Burnley"]      <- DP$DefenceHome[3] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "Chelsea"]          <- DP$DefenceHome[4] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "Crystal Palace"] <- DP$DefenceHome[5] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "Everton"]      <- DP$DefenceHome[6] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "Hull"]             <- DP$DefenceHome[7] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "Leicester"]        <- DP$DefenceHome[8] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "Liverpool"]        <- DP$DefenceHome[9] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "Man City"]         <- DP$DefenceHome[10] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "Man United"]   <- DP$DefenceHome[11] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "Middlesbrough"]    <- DP$DefenceHome[12] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "Southampton"]  <- DP$DefenceHome[13] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "Stoke"]            <- DP$DefenceHome[14] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "Sunderland"]   <- DP$DefenceHome[15] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "Swansea"]      <- DP$DefenceHome[16] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "Tottenham"]        <- DP$DefenceHome[17] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "Watford"]      <- DP$DefenceHome[18] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "West Brom"]        <- DP$DefenceHome[19] 
Model$DefenceHome[Model$Home == "West Ham"]         <- DP$DefenceHome[20] 

Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "Arsenal"]      <- DP$DefenceAway[1]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "Bournemouth"]  <- DP$DefenceAway[2]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "Burnley"]          <- DP$DefenceAway[3]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "Chelsea"]      <- DP$DefenceAway[4]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "Crystal Palace"] <- DP$DefenceAway[5]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "Everton"]          <- DP$DefenceAway[6]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "Hull"]         <- DP$DefenceAway[7]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "Leicester"]        <- DP$DefenceAway[8]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "Liverpool"]        <- DP$DefenceAway[9]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "Man City"]         <- DP$DefenceAway[10]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "Man United"]   <- DP$DefenceAway[11]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "Middlesbrough"]    <- DP$DefenceAway[12]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "Southampton"]  <- DP$DefenceAway[13]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "Stoke"]            <- DP$DefenceAway[14]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "Sunderland"]   <- DP$DefenceAway[15]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "Swansea"]      <- DP$DefenceAway[16]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "Tottenham"]        <- DP$DefenceAway[17]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "Watford"]      <- DP$DefenceAway[18]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "West Brom"]        <- DP$DefenceAway[19]
Model$DefenceAway[Model$Away == "West Ham" ]        <- DP$DefenceAway[20] 

Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "Arsenal"]           <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[1] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "Bournemouth"]       <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[2] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "Burnley"]           <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[3] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "Chelsea"]           <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[4] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "Crystal Palace"]        <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[5] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "Everton"]               <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[6] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "Hull"]              <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[7] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "Leicester"]             <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[8] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "Liverpool"]             <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[9] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "Man City"]          <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[10] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "Man United"]            <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[11] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "Middlesbrough"]         <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[12] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "Southampton"]       <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[13] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "Stoke"]                 <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[14] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "Sunderland"]            <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[15] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "Swansea"]           <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[16] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "Tottenham"]             <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[17] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "Watford"]           <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[18] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "West Brom"]             <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[19] 
Model$AverageHFShots[Model$Home == "West Ham"]          <- SoModel$AverageHFShots[20] 

Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "Arsenal"]           <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[1] 
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "Bournemouth"]       <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[2]
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "Burnley"]           <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[3]
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "Chelsea"]               <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[4]
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "Crystal Palace"]        <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[5]
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "Everton"]           <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[6]
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "Hull"]              <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[7]
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "Leicester"]             <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[8]
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "Liverpool"]             <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[9]
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "Man City"]          <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[10]
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "Man United"]            <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[11]
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "Middlesbrough"]         <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[12]
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "Southampton"]       <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[13]
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "Stoke"]                 <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[14]
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "Sunderland"]            <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[15]
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "Swansea"]               <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[16]
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "Tottenham"]             <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[17]
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "Watford"]           <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[18]
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "West Brom"]             <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[19]
Model$AverageAFShots[Model$Away == "West Ham" ]             <- SoModel$AverageAFShots[20] 

Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "Arsenal"]            <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[1]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "Bournemouth"]        <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[2]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "Burnley"]            <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[3]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "Chelsea"]            <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[4]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "Crystal Palace"]     <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[5]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "Everton"]            <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[6]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "Hull"]           <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[7]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "Leicester"]      <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[8]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "Liverpool"]      <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[9]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "Man City"]       <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[10]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "Man United"]         <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[11]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "Middlesbrough"]  <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[12]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "Southampton"]        <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[13]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "Stoke"]          <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[14]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "Sunderland"]         <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[15]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "Swansea"]            <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[16]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "Tottenham"]      <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[17]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "Watford"]            <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[18]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "West Brom"]      <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[19]
Model$HGoalPerShots[Model$Home == "West Ham"]       <- GRT$HGoalPerShots[20]

Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "Arsenal"]            <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[1]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "Bournemouth"]        <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[2]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "Burnley"]            <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[3]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "Chelsea"]            <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[4]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "Crystal Palace"]     <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[5]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "Everton"]            <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[6]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "Hull"]           <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[7]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "Leicester"]      <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[8]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "Liverpool"]      <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[9]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "Man City"]       <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[10]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "Man United"]         <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[11]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "Middlesbrough"]  <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[12]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "Southampton"]        <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[13]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "Stoke"]          <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[14]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "Sunderland"]         <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[15]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "Swansea"]            <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[16]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "Tottenham"]      <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[17]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "Watford"]            <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[18]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "West Brom"]      <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[19]
Model$AGoalPerShots[Model$Away == "West Ham" ]      <- GRT$AGoalPerShots[20]

Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "Arsenal"]         <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[1]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "Bournemouth"]     <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[2]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "Burnley"]         <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[3]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "Chelsea"]     <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[4]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "Crystal Palace"] <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[5]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "Everton"]         <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[6]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "Hull"]            <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[7]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "Leicester"]   <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[8]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "Liverpool"]   <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[9]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "Man City"]        <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[10]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "Man United"]  <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[11]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "Middlesbrough"] <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[12]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "Southampton"]     <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[13]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "Stoke"]       <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[14]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "Sunderland"]  <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[15]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "Swansea"]         <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[16]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "Tottenham"]   <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[17]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "Watford"]         <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[18]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "West Brom"]   <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[19]
Model$HConcedePerShots[Model$Home == "West Ham"]        <- GRT$HConcedePerShots[20]

Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "Arsenal"]         <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[1]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "Bournemouth"]     <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[2]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "Burnley"]     <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[3]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "Chelsea"]         <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[4]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "Crystal Palace"] <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[5]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "Everton"]     <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[6]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "Hull"]            <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[7]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "Leicester"]   <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[8]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "Liverpool"]   <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[9]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "Man City"]        <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[10]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "Man United"]  <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[11]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "Middlesbrough"] <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[12]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "Southampton"]     <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[13]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "Stoke"]       <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[14]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "Sunderland"]  <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[15]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "Swansea"]     <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[16]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "Tottenham"]   <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[17]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "Watford"]         <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[18]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "West Brom"]   <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[19]
Model$AConcedePerShots[Model$Away == "West Ham" ]   <- GRT$AConcedePerShots[20]

Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "Arsenal"]       <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[1] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "Bournemouth"]   <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[2] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "Burnley"]       <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[3] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "Chelsea"]       <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[4] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "Crystal Palace"]    <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[5] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "Everton"]           <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[6] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "Hull"]          <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[7] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "Leicester"]         <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[8] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "Liverpool"]         <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[9] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "Man City"]      <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[10] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "Man United"]        <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[11] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "Middlesbrough"]     <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[12] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "Southampton"]   <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[13] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "Stoke"]             <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[14] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "Sunderland"]        <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[15] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "Swansea"]       <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[16] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "Tottenham"]         <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[17] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "Watford"]       <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[18] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "West Brom"]         <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[19] 
Model$AverageHAShots[Model$Home == "West Ham"]      <- SoModel$AverageHAShots[20] 

Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "Arsenal"]       <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[1] 
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "Bournemouth"]   <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[2]
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "Burnley"]       <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[3]
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "Chelsea"]           <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[4]
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "Crystal Palace"]    <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[5]
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "Everton"]       <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[6]
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "Hull"]          <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[7]
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "Leicester"]         <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[8]
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "Liverpool"]         <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[9]
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "Man City"]      <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[10]
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "Man United"]        <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[11]
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "Middlesbrough"]     <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[12]
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "Southampton"]   <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[13]
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "Stoke"]             <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[14]
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "Sunderland"]        <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[15]
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "Swansea"]           <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[16]
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "Tottenham"]         <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[17]
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "Watford"]       <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[18]
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "West Brom"]         <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[19]
Model$AverageAAShots[Model$Away == "West Ham" ]         <- SoModel$AverageAAShots[20]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that I correctly understood the structure of your data, I would try something like this: create a list `citylist` with all your elements, than use `sapply`. Then you can either just replace the variable names in the last line, or create a second list where you store all variable names that you want to use and loop through them .

```
#dummy data
Home <- c("Arsenal","Arsenal","Bournemouth","Bournemouth","Burnley","Burnley","Burnley","Chelsea")
Model <- data.frame(Home)

AttackHome <- c("something1","something2","something3","something4")
AP <- data.frame(AttackHome)

#create the list
citylist <- list("Arsenal"=1,"Bournemouth"=2,"Burnley"=3,"Chelsea"=4)

#use sapply
Model$AttackHome <- sapply(Model$Home,function(x) {AP$AttackHome[citylist[[x]]]})
```